# How to use alternative encoding in specific gnome applications?

Tags: 11.04, encoding, character-set

Currently I'm trying to convert an Audio CD to ogg(s) using `asunder`, however, the encoding used in the CD (GB2312) is different to the current X session's (UTF-8):

[image: screenshot]

I tried to use a different one, but C library seems not support it:

```
$ LANG=zh_CN.GB2312 asunder
(process:19031): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
(... and the same screenshot ...)
```

P.S. I have installed the language-pack-*-zh, and the encoding GB2312 is supported by iconv:

```
$ iconv --list | grep GB2312
CSGB2312//
GB2312//
```

(I guess C library doesn't use iconv, however.)

Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `locale -a` to see the available locale definitions on your system. zh_CN.GB2312 is probably missing.

```
sudo localedef -f GB2312 -i zh_CN zh_CN.GB2312
```

should add that locale definition.